# Text Input reading a Color Picker value AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I am trying to code a Text Input to display the decimal color value. I have one color picker and one text input. Here is my code.

```
//Import
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.controls.TextInput;
import fl.controls.ColorPicker;
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;
//Variables
var ColorPickerThing:ColorPicker

this.ColorPickerThing.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE,ColorCode);

function ColorCode(event:ColorPickerEvent):void { 
    this.ColorValue.text = this.ColorPickerThing.selectedColor;
}
```

So in the end I want the decimal value for any color I pick to show up in the text input.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P86M.png

So if anyone could help it would be greatly apreciated. :)

I need help as this doesn't work. :/ I was hoping I could make it on my own but sadly my knowledge is limited. So I need help on making it work.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It isnt working that is why I am posting here.

Comment: "It isn't working" is not helpful - things can fail to work in many ways. We need to know what you expect to happen versus what is actually happening. Does nothing get put into the text input? Does it work once, but then not again? Does it always put the wrong color in? etc, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you haven't properly assigned any instance names and wired them to your variables in your code properly.

Try this code:

```
//Import
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.controls.TextInput;
import fl.controls.ColorPicker;
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;
//Variables
var ColorPickerThing:ColorPicker = my_color_picker;

this.ColorPickerThing.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE, ColorCode);

function ColorCode(event: ColorPickerEvent):void {
    this.my_color_picker_value.text = this.ColorPickerThing.selectedColor.toString();
}
```

And on your stage, set the instance name of the text field you are using to display the selected color to be 'my_color_picker_value' and set the instance name of the actual color picker component to be 'my_color_picker'.

Using your code as a starting point, I was able to create a working example in Flash CC using the code I've provided to you above.  In my example, when you select a color in the color picker component, the decimal value of that color is shown in the text field.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Amazing. This was exactly what I was looking for. I am going to try it now but thank you so much :) Amazing. IT works. Thank you so much :) Woot :)

Comment: Accepted. Thank you once more :)